# Select tag keeps expanding in second iframe

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm having difficulty populating the second iframe on this page:

http://www.licf.ronaldboadi.com/Movieshop/

Whenever you select an option in iframe 1, instead of iframe 2 being refreshed and a certain number of values being added - it keeps adding more values to the previous user selection. How can I stop this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: iframes? There is no need to use iframes for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear the document contents each load by setting the src to "about:blank". Generally, that works like:

```
iframe_el.src = "about:blank";
```

In you context, just put this right above the document opne.

```
with( document.getElementById('movie').contentDocument ) {
    src = "about:blank";
    open();
    write(hstr);
    close();
}
```

Also, as a general best practice, [don't use with](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#with). Just cache the object, like this:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('movie').contentDocument;
doc.src = "about:blank";
doc.open();
doc.write(hstr);
doc.close();
```